# how to target the second one with the first one and get another sheets with the results

Tags: filter, target, calc, unique-values

I have two sheets. The first one (document 1  as picture attached) contains only one colums with has unique number for each line (key). the second sheets (document 2 as picture attached) has multiple colums (name, adress...).
I want to keep only the persons which exists on doument 2 and which do have the number (key) which match the key in document 1.
In other words, i want to "filter" the document 2, colum "matricule famille" using the "matricule famille sans espace août23" from document 1 in order to get a list of the persons.

[document1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYdWW.png)
[document2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG1Ey.png)

i have tried "filter" method but i cannot paste the number from document1 in filer parameters (see document3 picture above.
[document3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsQur.png)

i dont know know how can i proceed in order to "paste" the numbers in document 2 using filter method? maybe there is another method but i ask for your help.
thank you vey much (merci!).

i cannot get the result i have explained below and i do not know how to proceed.